# Squeak Smalltalk getting "adaptToNumber:andSend:" error when creating linked list

Tags: list, smalltalk

I have defined list structure and now I am trying to create a list with some rules.
Here is the code so far:

```
List: aa 
   | i start current aNumber|
start := Test new setValue:2.
current := start.
aNumber:=3.
i:=0.
[i<=aa] whileTrue:[
current:=start.
[aNumber \\ current =0] whileFalse:  
       [[current getNext = nil] ifTrue:[current addLinkedVlue:aNumber. i=i+1].current:=current getNext].
aNumber:=aNumber+1].
```

I have method printListFrom which gets parameter aa. The aim is to get a list which has lenght of aa. The list can't contain numbers which can be divided without reminder by numbers which already are in list. Forexample, if list contains numbers: 2 3 5 and we need to check 6 then 6/2 = 3, it has no reminder, so we can't add it to the list. If we want to check 7, then  7/2=3 reminder 1, 7/3 =  2 reminder 1, 7/5 = 1 reminder 2, in this case we can add 7 to the list.

If we have that aa = 3, as a result I must get list which has 3 numbers(2 3 5), if aa = 4, then list should be (2 3 5 7) and so on.

In my code, in whileTrue loop I divide aNumber by number in the list (current), if I get that reminder is 0 I just add 1 to aNumber, if reminder is greater than 0 then I divide aNumber by next number in list, if I have divided aNumber by all numbers in list and got some reminder after every division I add 1 to i which represents the lenght of the list, and I add also aNumber to the list.

Code is not running well, i am getting :

```
MessageNotUnderstood: adaptToNumber:andSend:
```

and I don't know whats wrong.

Here is declaration of other methods which I have declared and used in List method:

```
setValue: i 
a := i.

getNext
^next


addLinkedValue: n
next := Test new setValue: n.
```

Comment: There's another problem pending: condition (the receiver of ifTrue:) must not be a Block of code [...] - the condition will be evaluated unconditionnally, but you wrote `[current getNext = nil] ifTrue:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
[aNumber \\ current] whileFalse:
```

because `aNumber` is an `Integer` but `current` isn't. In fact `current` is an instance of the `Test` class and therefore `aNumber` doesn't know how to deal with the message `\\` when the argument (`current` in this case) is not an `Integer`.

What the receiver `aNumber` does to try to resolve this problem is to ask the argument to cope with the situation, and to do so it informs the argument to `adaptToInteger: aNumber andSend: #quo:`.

Note that the selector is not `\\` but `quo:`. The reason is in the way `\\` is implemented, which makes the receiver realize that the argument is not an `Integer` not before sending it the message `quo:`.

Now, given that you haven't implemented `adaptToInteger:andSend:` in `Test` the implementation inherited from `Object` enters the scene and the instance of `Test` receives `adaptToNumber:andSend:`, which is more general.

A solution would then consist in implementing this method in `Test` as

```
adaptToNumber: aNumber andSend: aSymbol
    ^aNumber perform: aSymbol withArgument: a
```

which delegates the message to the (numeric) instance variable `a`.

Having said this, I would recommend you to also revise the code trying to make it simpler.

Comment: So, `[aNumber \\ current value=0] whileFalse:` could possibly work if value is defined in Test...

Comment: @aka.nice Good idea. However, I still think that the code deserves a complete revision.